# How do I perform multiple actions in the review queue?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

**The problem:**
I have started using the review queues to help with editing and/or closing questions. If I edit a question and save the edits, the queue automatically goes to the next question. If I choose to keep a question open or close a question, the queue automatically goes to the next question.

**The Question:**
How do I stop the queue from going to the next question after a successful edit? I would like to be able to close or keep the question open after making an edit.

Comment: ctrl-click on the linky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of editing from the close queue is to say that *you can turn the question into a good question with your edit*, and thus it no longer merits closure.  As such, editing a question is casting a leave open vote.

If you don't think you can edit the question into one *that should still be open* after your edit, then you shouldn't be editing it at all.

Comment: I was editing things like misspelled words and grammatical error.

Comment: @Sedrick And did those changes result in the question not meriting closure, after you had finished editing it?

Comment: Some were good questions, which made it okay to move on. Some were not good questions. Those are the ones, I wanted to vote to close. I am guessing, I should just cast a close vote in the future.

Comment: @Sedrick To quote the answer, "If you don't think you can edit the question into one that should still be open after your edit, then you shouldn't be editing it at all."

Comment: @Sedrick "*I was editing things like misspelled words and grammatical error*" that's fine if the question is open, could arguably be reopened, or your edit fixes the reason it was closed (ie can be re-opened). But consider the usefulness of editing a closed question to fix (eg) grammar. Unless it'll be re-opened it'll just disappear so your time spent editing could have been better elsewhere.